# Changing the emulator screen resolution?

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

How to change the emulator screen resolution to without keyboard mode?

Comment: I mean, i'm using 2.3.1. (Emulator). I can't hide the keyboard, I don't need the keyboard, how to hide this? Is it possible using resolution. If possible means tell me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use `480 x 800` in your emulator size when you've created the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

for changing resolution you have to open AVD manager and

- select the running emulator
- click on edit
- Avd windows open ,then select option resolution
- fill resolution you want  example 540x960

Comment: But screen resolution input fields are disabled in my AVD manager. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if its possible to hide the keyboard, but another solution is to open you're running configuration manager and to set -scale parameter inside the "target" tab at the bottom on the option for adding additional configurations. I think you can use values from 0.1 to 3.0, for example i have a 14" screen and i just use 0.8 scale and it works fine.
Hope it helps you.